# Как получить цвет строки посылаемой программой в output

Tags: c#

Запуская программу через cmd иногда программа возвращает подсвеченную строку например вот так подсвечивает строку node.exe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я предполагаю программа делает что вроде

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
Console.ResetColor();
```

Могу ли я получить цвет если я запускаю эту же программу из C# используя System.Diagnostics.Process ?
я использую такой код для запуска процесса и получения output

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "node.exe",
        Arguments = fileName,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
proc.Exited += Proc_Exited;
proc.ErrorDataReceived += Proc_ErrorDataReceived;
proc.OutputDataReceived += Proc_OutputDataReceived; ;
proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();



private static void Proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var proc = sender as Process;
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

Comment: [ReadConsoleOutputAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutputattribute) должен помочь.